# Как получить ping определенного ip по определенному внешнему сетевому интерфейсу на выбор через выпадающий список?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit, httpclient, ping

Добрый день. Возникла необходимость создать простое android приложение, в котором нужно через команду ping проверить определенные IP адреса, например 127.0.0.1, по аналогии с утилитой ping, запущенной через командную строку cmd.exe на винде.

[image: команда ping запущенная через командную строку cmd.exe в виндовс]

Использую библиотеку Retrofit 2. Не понятен алгоритм действий, который нужно выполнить. По моим соображениям, необходимо среди прочего создать класс RestClient (здесь пример для взаимодействия с сервером ВК)

```
public class RestClient {
private static final String VK_BASE_URL = "https://api.vk.com/method/";

private Retrofit mRetrofit;

public RestClient() {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();



    mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(VK_BASE_URL)
            .client(httpClient)
            .build();
}

public <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
    return mRetrofit.create(serviceClass);
}
```

}

И Далее создать интерфейсы для взаимодействия с restapi.

Comment: А зачем сразу retrofit тянуть? Он предназначен для HTTP запросов, а сетевой пинг меряется совсем по другому протоколу. А то у вас тут и Rx и Gson, к чему все это?

Comment: Предполагал, что для получения пинга нужно http запросы использовать через retrofit. Подскажите свое решение?

Comment: Самый простой путь вам уже подсказали в одном из ответов. Второй, сложный можете начать с изучения теории https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут нужно понимать как работает shell.

```
private String executeCommand(String command) { 
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            p.waitFor();
            BufferedReader reader =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return output.toString();

    }
```

Как то так код выглядит на java. Вам только нужно погуглить как на linuxе правильно прописать команду пинг. Как итог в конце прийдет строка с результатами.

Comment: На подобии такой команды "/system/bin/ping -c 8 " ? Получается, что в метод executeCommand должна прийти команда  "/system/bin/ping -c 8 " + какой нибудь url или ip?

Comment: [клик ми](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576710/ping-application-in-android) думаю это самый лучший пример)

Comment: Да, этот пример по ссылке работает